# Creating a ChildObject in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am working on a data import into an application in PowerShell through the Business Object Interface of that application (Sage 100 ERP software).

In VBScript i used the following line to get a handle for the oLines object:

`Set oLines  = oSession.AsObject(oHeader.Lines)`

oSession and oHeader are established objects. In my Powershell script these objects are $oSession and $oHeader.

What would the above code look like in Powershell?

Comment: Look into `add-member -?`

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how to get to the Lines object with add-member. Could you clarify?

Comment: `$oHeader | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name Lines -value SomeSampleText` https://ss64.com/ps/add-member.html

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but I am trying to get to a Lines Object that belongs to the HeaderObject. I am not trying to add a property to the Header object.

Comment: I don't know vbs that much sorry... Can you explain what it does more then?

Comment: My line of code makes the Lines Child object of a Header object accessible. oSession is a com object from the application that I am working with.